# Using variables as a hash keys in twig (as a parameters in path() or |trans)

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to use trans filter or path function dynamically?With variables as parameters?
ex1:

```
{{ path('object_edit', { parameter_type : parameter_value }) }}
```

because: I don't know if "object" using id or slug for routing

ex2:

```
{{message|trans({ parameter_type : parameter_value }, 'TranslationDomain') }}
```

because: i don't know if it will be '%user%' or '%article%' or something else

Why this works fine:

```
{{ path('object_edit', { 'id' : parameter_value }) }}
```

but this doesn't:

```
{{ set parameter_type = 'id' }}
{{ path('object_edit', { parameter_type : parameter_value }) }}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
{% set key = 'foobar' %}
{% set hash = { (key) : 'hello world' } %}
{% debug hash %}
```

prints:

```
array(1) { ["foobar"]=> string(11) "hello world" }
```

wrapping in parenthesis solves your problem.

Answer (score 23):

Enclose the hash keys with parenthesis (not braces).

```
{{ path('object_edit', { (parameter_type) : parameter_value }) }}
```